# Active Appearance Model texture normalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement on MATLAB the photometric normalization step of the Active Appearance Model, as described here http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~aam/main/node13.html#SECTION04350000000000000000

The code I have is the following:

```
function g=AAM_NormalizeAppearance3D(gim_mat)

n_texs = size(gim_mat,1); % Number of array elements
s = size(gim_mat,2); % Number of textures

mean_tex = gim_mat(:,1); % First mean texture is considered to be the first one in the set

tex_error = 1;

oneloop = false;

while tex_error > 0.001 % Convergence criteria

    mean_tex = mean_tex - mean(mean_tex); % Standardize mean texture
    sig = sqrt(sum(mean_tex.^2)/n_texs);
    mean_tex = mean_tex/sig;

    if oneloop % prev_mean_tex is still not defined in first iteration
        tex_error = sum(abs((prev_mean_tex - mean_tex)));
    end

    for i=1:s
        alpha = dot(gim_mat(:,i), mean_tex);
        beta = mean(gim_mat(:,i)); 

        gim_mat(:,i) = (gim_mat(:,i) - beta)/ alpha; % Normalized texture vector
    end

    prev_mean_tex = mean_tex; % Store previous mean texture
    mean_tex = mean(gim_mat,2); % New mean texture

    oneloop = true;
end

g = gim_mat;
```

Now, I don't know if I'm interpreting wrong the results I'm getting from this or if there's any error in the code, but the normalized texture values I get are extremely small. That is, for input texture vectors with values ranging from 0 to 1, I'm getting normalized vectors with maximum values of the order of 10^-5. Shouldn't this converge to higher values?